# Confirming that yum-cron is configured properly on a CentOS 7 server

Tags: security, yum, centos7

Is there any way to test whether `yum-cron` is configured properly? I need to confirm that it will automatically install security patches and that it will email me when it does so.

I have a CentOS 7 web server with `yum-cron` installed. It's been running for a few months and I haven't received any emails, nor do I see any updates in `/var/log/yum.log`. I *think* this is because there haven't actually been any security updates affecting me. When I run `yum --security list updates` I get the message `No packages needed for security`, and I don't see any recent critical patches affecting me in [centos-announce](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/).

My `/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf` looks something like the following, with a real email address instead of `administrator@example.com`:

```
[commands]
update_cmd = security
update_messages = yes
download_updates = yes
apply_updates = yes

[emitters]
emit_via = stdio,email

[email]
email_from = root@localhost
email_to = root,administrator@example.com
email_host = localhost
```

Answer (score 7):

Your test looks right, but AFAICT the problem is that the main CentOS repositories unfortunately don't come with the required information to support security-only updates the way RHEL does. Please refer to this discussion for the details:

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=51300

On CentOS it looks like you can only really use yum-cron for automatic full upgrades as in:

```
update_cmd = default
```

otherwise you only get security upgrades from any external repositories you happen to use (like e.g. EPEL).

On our own CentOS 7 servers we use that default combined with download and notify-only rules, which we then manually act on.

As a workaround you could probably maintain a local yum repository with only the security updates and automatically apply full upgrades from there. It would still require manual maintenance of that security repository, but then at least all your servers could auto upgrade from there.

Comment: +1 Also CentOS/RHEL is so conservative/stable with default updates that I doubt any self-developed attempt to "improve" will actually improve OS availability. If you go non-standard, you absolutely need to test updates first.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see if the job is running by the cron log.

`grep yum.cron /var/log/cron | tail -10`

If you see output here you can then verify.

```
tail -10 /var/log/yum.log
```

Comment: For rotated logs: `tail -n 10 /var/log/yum.log*`

Answer (score 0):

You can test this. Find a host that's behind on updates compared to the announce list.  Or, if they are all up to date, build a new one and *don't* apply all the updates yet. Apply your config and wait for the email.